# datapicker automatic selection plus 1- 7 days from selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to set auto select +7 days. User set first value e.g. 22.02.2022 and datapicker marks 01.03.2022 it means that endDate must be startDate +7

```
 $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
          {
            dateFormat: "MMMM D, YYYY",
            timePicker: true,
            startDate: moment(),
            endDate: moment().startOf("days").add(7, "days"),
            opens: "left",
            applyButtonClasses: "Search",
          },




var startDate = $("#datarange").data("daterangepicker").startDate._d;
      var startDate_iso = startDate.toISOString();


   if (
    startDate_iso.substring(0, 10) == new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
  ) {
    //[wyl] dateCurrent = new Date();
    //[wyl] interval_do = dateCurrent.toISOString();

    var startDate = $("#datarange").data("daterangepicker").startDate._d;
    var startDate_iso = startDate.toISOString();
    var endDate = $("#datarange").data("daterangepicker").endDate._d;
    var endDate_iso = endDate.toISOString();
    interval = startDate_iso + "/" + endDate_iso;
    console.log("A new date was set: " + startDate_iso + " to " + endDate_iso);
}
  else {
    var startDate = $("#datarange").data("daterangepicker").startDate._d;
    var startDate_iso = startDate.toISOString();
    var endDate = $("#datarange").data("daterangepicker").endDate._d;
    var endDate_iso = endDate.toISOString();
    interval = startDate_iso + "/" + endDate_iso;
    console.log("A new date was set: " + startDate_iso + " to " + endDate_iso);
    console.log("==================== Select date ================");
}
```

I have tried min / max but this is not the expected solution. it just allows me to return a date from the default to +7 days.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Why do you have an `else` but no `if` statement? You have some bugs in your code kindly update.

Comment: This seems to be what you're asking: [how to add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date)

Comment: It doesn't work. I have to do something like in my object. when i select 01.03.2022 max dater return min date +7 days. And convert it toISOString